# CustomScrollView not detecting scrolling

Tags: flutter, customscrollview

I am new to flutter and wondering if someone could help me with a scroll mechanic. I am trying out `SliverAppBar` for the first time and it is working correctly with movements of the bar itself. However, I have a `ListView.builder` that builds widgets that I placed within a sliverfillremaining and it is not detecting the movements of the list. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('appName')],),
            expandedHeight: 110,
            floating: true,
            pinned: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('my text 1', style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                      ),
                      softWrap: true,),
                      Text('my Text', style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                         ),),],),),),),),

          SliverFillRemaining(
            hasScrollBody: true,
            child: Container(
              child: NoteList(
                  items: items,
                ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

NoteList

```
class NoteList extends StatelessWidget {

  const NoteList({
    @required this.items, 
  });

  final List<Note> items;

  Future _navigateToNote(BuildContext context, Note note) => Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NoteScreen(note)),
  );

  Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int position) {
    final cardShape = const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0)),
    );
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:0, bottom: 0),
      child: Card(
        shape: cardShape,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () => _navigateToNote(context, items[position]),
          customBorder: cardShape,
       child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('${items[position].theItem}',             
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 2),
        itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also create ScrollController. That will also solve your problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `ListView` inside `CustomScrollView`. Both are scrollable so the conflict occurs.

To solve the problem, replace `ListView` with `SliverList` — special widget for displaying list of items inside `CustomScrollView`.

`SliverFillRemaining` isn't needed here, so the code will be:

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverAppBar(
        ...
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (context, index) => Card(
            // any nested widgets
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(items[index].name),
            ),
          ),
          childCount: items.length,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I saw I had previously tried the sliverlist, but was not getting it to work. I appreciate the help